# Error compiling apache2.4.25 on Ubuntu 22

Tags: apache2, openssl

I'm trying to compile apache2.4.25 on Ubuntu and APR and APR Utils are already installed, OpenSSL was version 1.1.0h and Im getting some erros like:

```
/usr/local/apr/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lpthread  \
         -o ab  ab.lo       /usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.la -lcrypt -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: ab.o: in function `ssl_print_cert_info':
/home/me/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:650: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_bits'
/usr/bin/ld: ab.o: in function `ssl_print_info':
/home/me/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:681: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate'
/usr/bin/ld: ab.o: in function `ssl_proceed_handshake':
/home/me/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:714: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:716: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_bits'
/usr/bin/ld: ab.o: in function `main':
/home/me/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:2398: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:2468: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_malloc_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: [Support for SSLv2 and the corresponding SSLv2_method(), SSLv2_server_method() and SSLv2_client_method() functions where removed in OpenSSL 1.1.0.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSLv23_client_method.html#HISTORY)

Comment: Strange, I'm trying to rebuild an image of an application for testing and in that image there's PHP 5.3.16 running, which is already compiled and working, and Apache2.4.25 and Openssl 1.1.0f, this problem can be worked around by disabling something in Apache